# Puesta del sol or puesta de sol, which is more correct?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática

"Puesta de sol" or "puesta del sol", which is more correct to use for "sunset"? I would think "del sol", since sol is masculine, but I have heard and seen both used frequently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct

By principle "del" should be the correct pronunciation, but in Spanish as matter of respect, when talking about specific or unique beings/things, we won't use "del" or "de la", we would just use "de".

Examples:

> De Dios
>   De luna
>   De sol
>   De "Person Name"

Why is like this ?
Because "del" is the contraction of "de" and "el", and is used to specify something, but if something is unique, then there's no need to specify it.

For my personal use I would use either one depending on the context:

if i'm talking about the sun

> you can play until the sun sets
>   pueden jugar hasta la puesta del sol

if i'm talking about the whole sunset in specific

> this sunset was beautiful
>   esta puesta de sol fue hermosa

Answer (score 0):

Additional possibility -- avoid this slightly awkward phrase and use a more natural choice of words:

**atardecer**

> El atardecer fue hermoso.

**irse la luz**

> Pueden jugar hasta que se vaya la luz.

**hacerse noche**

> Ya se hizo noche. | *It's after sunset.*